# Table in reverse order

Tags: c++

I was doing basic programming to print the n's table in reverse order where n is a positive integer.
Here is my approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;

    cin >> n;
    int multiplier = 10;
    while (multiplier--)
    {
       n = n*multiplier;
       cout << n << endl;
    }
}
```

But its output is not what I expected. May I know where is the problem lying in this code? Also, please do provide me some advice as after 2 months I am having MS intern interview.

My input was

```
2
```

Output came out to be

```
18
144
1008
6048
30240
120960
362880
725760
725760
0
```

Comment: You didn't mention what the output was or what the input is.  Also, isn't learning how to debug your own programs part of this interview you say you're having?

Comment: `n=n*multiplier;` think, what is that line actually doing 

Comment: Got it, the problem was lying in this part as the original number is always changed by me.

Comment: Minor nitpick: The `stream << std::endl` does `stream << "\n"; stream.flush();` which is, in most cases, causing your program to perform worse than a simple `stream  << "\n"`. If you can motivate the flushing with "_this is a file that people "tail -f" so it'll need to get instant updates_" you are fine.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you probably don't want to change `n` every iteration, so I suggest you assign the calculation to another (scoped) variable:

```
int main()
{
    int n;

    cin >> n;

    int multiplier = 10;
    while (multiplier--)
    {
        int nn = n*multiplier;
        cout << nn << endl;
    }
}
```

Another thing: you might want to actually see the 10*n printed first (and not the "0" at the end), so you could also multiply `n` by `multiplier+1` (or do a `do-while` loop instead).

Comment: But why we need another variable for it?

Comment: Because you keep changing the original variable `n` every iteration. You will easily notice that if you'd step through your code with a debugger.

Comment: Because you don't need :-) `cout << n*multiplier << endl;`

Comment: @bruno - of course, that's the next step. That local variable doesn't actually need to out-live the `cout` statement.

Comment: @uv_ I know you know, this was mainly a joke, _why we need ? ... because you don't_ :-)

Comment: Got you, @bruno :)